# How to display node teaser in Display Suite custom field?

Tags: 7, display-suite, entities

I am trying to create custom Display Suite code field.

I would like to show truncated text of node body or teaser if exists (+ other stuff, like: (...) and link to current node)

I tried to use [node:teaser] but nothing was showed.
I tried to use [node:body:?] token too, but all options I have tried failed for me.

Field code:

```
[node:teaser] (...) <a class="read-more" href="[node:url]"><?php print t('read more'); ?></a>
```

Any suggestions?

It so basic thing but I have no idea what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: are you using views? or from the full content you need to display the teaser?

Comment: I am using Views, anyway I solved this by creating preprocess function for this field inside template.php.

Comment: Mind posting your answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this by adding a preprocess field which then becomes available in DS.

```
<?php
      function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
        // Get the summary as a discrete field.
        $body = array_pop(field_get_items('node', $variables['node'], 'body'));
        $variables['node_summary'] = $body['safe_summary'];
      }
```

Then in display suite add a preprocess field named node_summary.